# Why does "StratifiedShuffleSplit" give the same result for every split of dataset?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction

I'm using `StratifiedShuffleSplit` to repeat the procedure of split dataset, fit, predict, and compute metric. Could you please explan why it gives the same result for every split?

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

clf = RandomForestClassifier(max_depth = 5)
df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/leanhdung1994/BigData/main/cll_dataset.csv")
X, y = df.iloc[:, 1:], df.iloc[:, 0]
sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 5, test_size = 0.25, random_state = 0).split(X, y)

for train_ind, test_ind in sss:
    X_train, X_test = X.loc[train_ind], X.loc[test_ind]
    y_train, y_test = y.loc[train_ind], y.loc[test_ind]
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    report = classification_report(y_test, y_pred, zero_division = 0, output_dict = True)
    report = pd.DataFrame(report).T
    report = report[:2]
    print(report)
```

The result is

```
   precision  recall  f1-score  support
0       0.75     1.0  0.857143      6.0
1       0.00     0.0  0.000000      2.0
   precision  recall  f1-score  support
0       0.75     1.0  0.857143      6.0
1       0.00     0.0  0.000000      2.0
   precision  recall  f1-score  support
0       0.75     1.0  0.857143      6.0
1       0.00     0.0  0.000000      2.0
   precision  recall  f1-score  support
0       0.75     1.0  0.857143      6.0
1       0.00     0.0  0.000000      2.0
   precision  recall  f1-score  support
0       0.75     1.0  0.857143      6.0
1       0.00     0.0  0.000000      2.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every model you build, predicts that the output is always class 0, and, as you have stratified split (always have same proportion of class 0  and class 1 than the X), you always predict exactly same values.

The models obtain better accuracy when they predicts always class 0, than "learning" some pattern or rule. This is a huge problem. To solve it you have some options below:

- Try modifying some hyperparameters of the Random Forest algorithm.
- Collect more data in order to obtain a bigger dataset, you only test with 8 samples (maybe is
  difficult obtain new data for you)
- You have unbalanced data (more samples of class 0 than class 1), you
  should consider balancing it using `SMOTE` library